# Creating a regular expression for this type of dates

Tags: php, regex, date

I would first like to thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I am trying to write a regular expression to detect different formats of dates and I've found many questions regarding this but none to which fit my requirements.

Here are some examples of what I need to detect

```
16 SEPTEMBER 2016 
October 2016
8/2016
11/03/2016
```

and this is the bit of code I started with, I got kind of stuck and don't know how to go on from here.
What I want to do is basically have more than 1 option per / , for example month can be in words or numbers and year can be 93 or 1993

here is my code

```
(\d\d)+]?.?(\d\d)?\w{3,9}?.(\d\d\d\d)?|(\d\d)?
```

Thank you so much for your responses in advance!

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show us various example of strings? test this in javascript, is same for php: '16 SEPTEMBER 2016 October 2016 8/2016 11/03/2016'.match(/([0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/kU2xB5/1. It might be matching more date formats than you need though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but since PHP uses Perl regex functions as an extension, here's a Perl program that prints out dates from an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@array = ('16 SEPTEMBER 2016', 'October 2016', '8/2016', '18/2016', '11/03/2016', 'NOT A DATE 3534');

for $date (@array){
    if($date =~ /^(\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]+ \d{4}$)|(^[A-Za-z]+ \d{4}$)|(^\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$)|(^\d{2}\/d{2}\/\d{4}$)/){
        print "$date\n";
    }
}
```

If needed, you could write a slightly more complex program that checks against a list of acceptable months rather than matching any string of letters.

Let me know if this helps.